# Svelte (Express & Axios) - http 500 error on put method

Tags: express, axios, svelte

I'm at a loss. I have a svelte application (Backend: Express, Frontend: Axios). I have a MongoDB with locations. Locations have an array of bands. And I want to add bands to this array. The backend seems to work fine, at least with Postman it works. But when I try to add a band through the frontend, I get a http 500 error.

This is the back end code:

```
app.put('/api/locations/:location', async (req, res) => {

let location = req.params.location;
let updatedlocation = req.body;


try {
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db('Concerts');
    const collection = database.collection('locations');
    const query = { locationname: location };
    const result = await collection.updateOne(query, { $set: updatedlocation });

    if (result.matchedCount === 0) {
        let responseBody = {
            status: "No Location under the name " + location
        }
        res.status(404).send(responseBody);
    }
    else {
        res.send({ status: "Location " + location + " has been updated." });
    }
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
}})
```

This is the method in the frontend:

```
function addConcert() {
    location.concerts.push(chosenband);
    console.log("http://localhost:3001/api/locations/" +name);
    console.log(location);
    axios.put("http://localhost:3001/api/locations/" +name, location)
        .then((response) => {
            alert("Konzert wurde hinzugefügt");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert("Nope");
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Info: the {chosenband} comes from a select. This seems to work as well, as the console logs show.
The object is correct and includes the new band:

[this is the log from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93sAL.png)

So the object seems fine. Also the put-url is correct.

[But I always get this 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni9G1.png)

Thankful for any advise!

Comment: I recommend adding a `console.error(error)` inside your `catch error {...} on the backend, or using the debugger. Will give you more information to work with.

Comment: You should also log `location` and `updatedLocation` after they've been assigned in your route handler on the backend side, and verify they both hold the expected data when you trigger an update on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I didn't instantiate the location correctly. First I instantiated it simply as

```
let location = {}
```

, that didn't work. When I instantiated it with all the attributes

```
let location = {example:"", second:""}
```

it worked. Thanks for your help